# Go through the indexes of an array in a specific way

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int n;
    int *weight;
    int index,container;
    cout<<"Enter number of weights (1<=number<=10^5) you have: "<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    
    weight = new int[n];
    
    cout<<"Enter "<<n<<" number of weights (0<=weights<10^4) to the array:"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    cin>>weight[i]; 
    }
  
    int i=0; 
    
    while(i<n){ 
        index=weight[0]+4;    
        if(index!=weight[i]){
            container++;
            index=weight[i]+4;
        }   
    i++;            
    }
    cout<<container<<endl;      
    return 0;
}
```

First, input the array size(number) and then input the elements of the array(weights). We think all the inputs of the array are sorted.
Then the output should print the number of containers.
We think 8 weights input for the array (1,2,3,7,12,14,21,22) like that. And one container can load only minimum weight + 4 weights.
Ex: container 1 - 1,2,3 , container 2 - 7, container 3 - 12,14, container 4 - 21,22 like that. Container 1's minimum weight is 1 then it can load 1,2,3,4,5 weights only. From 6th weight onward it should be load on another container until 6(minimum weight)+4 10. And so on.

This is the code for I write for that problem. But when it takes the minimum weight it gets it the wrong way. If 1,2,3,4,5,6 are in the array. This code gets all the elements as minimum weight. But it should get 1 as the minimum weight and (1+4) 1,2,3,4,5 load into one container and 6 loads to another container. How should I correct this issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: `container++` leads to undefined behavior as `container` isn't initialized.

Comment: I can't say I understand the problem description (what is a container?) but I can see one error immeidately First `int index,container;` then `container++;`. You are incrementing `container` when it has never been given a value. Try this `int index,container=0;`

Comment: And are you sure you want to do `index=weight[0]+4;` inside the loop? Please take some time to some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is to count how many containers are needed to store N items, where all items in a given container weigh at most 4 more than the lowest weight item in that container.

The following should help (it assumes that the array of weights is sorted in ascending order):

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int LEN = 8;
    int weight[LEN] = {1,2,3,7,12,14,21,22};
  
    int container_index = 0;
    int container_count = (LEN > 0) ? 1 : 0;
    
    for (int ii = 0; ii < LEN; ii++) { 
        if (weight[ii] > weight[container_index] + 4) {
            container_count++;
            container_index = ii;
        }   
    }

    cout << container_count << endl;    

    return 0;
}
```

Results are:

- `[1,2,3,7,12,14,21,22]` => 4 containers (`[1,2,3]`, `[7]`, `[12,14]`, and `[21,22]`)
- `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` => 2 containers (`[1,2,3,4,5]` and `[6]`)

One final comment: you're using C++ but you've used C-style code and arrays, so I've done the same in my response. An idiomatic C++ solution would likely use vectors rather than arrays, for example.